# Es posible Mostrar / imprimir JSON con formato HTML

Tags: php, html5, json

Tengo un problema con un JSON, el problema es que estoy recibiendo una ficha tecnica desde un JSON. El problema no es consultar la información, el problema que tengo es que no siempre es la misma información en el JSON, me explico, en algunas fichas técnicas los primeros dos campos pueden ser **Tipo de producto** y **Numero de etiquetas por rollo**, pero en otras fichas técnicas los primeros campos son **Tipo de producto** y el segundo es **gestionable**

El problema es que por ejemplo si yo quisiera hacer lo siguiente:

> $producto = $array['ficha_tecnica'][etiquetas_por_rollo];

Algunas veces me daría error por que algunas fichas técnicas no tienen este campo y de aquí surge mi duda si es posible que en lugar de procesar el json lo pueda imprimir con un formato HTML?

Adjunto algunas imágenes de las diferencias entre los json que puedo recibir en las fichas técnicas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías usar bucles `foreach` para iterar el **JSON**. Lo bueno de estos bucles es que no tienes que conocer los índices para poder iterar un **objeto** o un **array**.

En mi ejemplo uso primero un bucle `foreach` para iterar por cada objeto del **array** y un segundo bucle para iterar por cada propiedad del **objeto** imprimiendo tanto su **clave** como su **valor**.

```
<?php

$frutas_string = '[{"nombre":"manzana", "color":"verde", "precio":"2.00€"}, {"nombre":"fresa", "propietario":"Pepe"}]';
$frutas = json_decode($frutas_string);
$contador = 1;

foreach ($frutas as $fruta) {
    echo '<b>Fruta número ' . $contador . '</b><br>';
    
    foreach ($fruta as $clave => $valor) {
        echo $clave . ' - ' . $valor . '<br>';
    }
    
    echo '<br>';
    
    $contador++;
}
```

**Salida:**

```
Fruta número 1
nombre - manzana
color - verde
precio - 2.00€

Fruta número 2
nombre - fresa
propietario - Pepe
```

De esta manera aunque los objetos tengan diferentes propiedades nos daría lo mismo porque vas a poder capturar el valor de cada una de ellas.

Comment: Entiendo, no es mala idea, entonces con esta solución podría pasar todo a una variable he imprimirla con algún formato html, voy a probar si me funciona, muchas gracias :D

Answer (score 0):

Hola podrías hacerlo si la variable existe o no intenta con esto:

```
$producto = $array['ficha_tecnica'][etiquetas_por_rollo];
if(!isset($producto)){
echo "no tiene ficha";
}else{
echo $producto;}
```

Oh hacerlo atraves de AJAX

Comment: Las respuestas de solo código se consideran de baja calidad, por favor lee [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -1):

pero cual es el problema si ¿lo tiene o no?, ya que accedes al objeto via `key o indice`, en caso de que tengas diferente vistas para cada uno puedes probar con `ficha_tecnica.hasOwnProperty("etiquetas_por_rollo")` aunque segun tu `JSON` quearia algo así

```
$.get(uri,function(res){
    if(res.hasOwnProperty("etiquetas por rollo")){
        alert("etiquetas por rollo");
    }
    if(res.hasOwnProperty("gestionable")){
        alert("gestionable");
    }     
})
```

En caso de ser una única vista puedes validarlo de esta manera

```
//Javascript
var rollo = res['etiquetas por rollo'] || "";

//PHP >7.3
$rollo = array['ficha_tecnica']['etiquetas_por_rollo'] ?? "";
```